# ViewPager became show incorrect pages after update of the support libraries

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-support-library

I updated the Google support libraries to rev. `23.2.0`. And `ViewPager` became show wrong page views.

`ViewPager` uses a custom page transformer:

```
private class ZoomOutPageTransformer implements ViewPager.PageTransformer {

    private static final float MIN_SCALE = 0.85f;

    private float mCenterOffset;
    private boolean mIsFixedCenterOffset = false;

    public void transformPage(View view, float position) {
        final int pageWidth = view.getWidth();
        final int pageHeight = view.getHeight();

        if(!mIsFixedCenterOffset) {
            mCenterOffset = position;
            mIsFixedCenterOffset = true;
        }

        position -= mCenterOffset;

        if (position <= 1) {
            final float scaleFactor = Math.max(MIN_SCALE, 1 - Math.abs(position));
            final float vertMargin = pageHeight * (1 - scaleFactor) / 2;
            final float horzMargin = pageWidth * (1 - scaleFactor) / 2;

            if (position < 0) {
                view.setTranslationX(horzMargin - vertMargin / 2);
            } else {
                view.setTranslationX(-horzMargin + vertMargin / 2);
            }

            view.setScaleX(scaleFactor);
            view.setScaleY(scaleFactor);
        }
    }
}
```

And has page margin:

```
ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) v.findViewById(R.id.vpDaySlider);
mAdapter = new DayPagerAdapter(getActivity(), fm, mWeekNumber);
viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(this);
viewPager.setPageTransformer(false, new ZoomOutPageTransformer());
Point display = SettingsManager.getDisplaySize(getContext());
final int padding = (int)(display.x * 0.1);
viewPager.setPageMargin(padding);
```

Now, it looks like below:

[image]

I even don't know where bug is... How to fix it? I need to page fills  parent space and scales down only on scrolling.

Warning in LogCat:

> W/FragmentManager: moveToState: Fragment state for DayFragment{24ec179 #2 id=0x7f0c00b4} not updated inline; expected state 3 found 2

**ADDED**
I realized what a bug. `ZoomOutPageTransformer` fixes the first position of page. And it must be 0 or nearly at zero but after update the first value of position > 1 (for example 1.1 on my phone) but the next (second) value is real page position (for my phone: 0). 

Because of what is happening? I think it's a wrong behaviour of `ViewPager`.

Comment: mark your question as solved!!

Comment: This is my solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/37000323/1983018

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I fixed this bug so:

```
private static class ZoomOutPageTransformer implements ViewPager.PageTransformer {

        private static final float MIN_SCALE = 0.85f;

        private ViewPager mViewPager;
        private float mPositionFixer;
        private boolean isSetFixer = false;

        public  ZoomOutPageTransformer(ViewPager viewPager) {
            mViewPager = viewPager;
        }

        public void transformPage(View view, float position) {
            final int pageWidth = view.getWidth();
            final int pageHeight = view.getHeight();

            if(!isSetFixer) {
                final int mClientWidth = mViewPager.getMeasuredWidth() -
                        mViewPager.getPaddingLeft() - mViewPager.getPaddingRight();
                mPositionFixer = ((float)mViewPager.getPaddingStart()) / mClientWidth;
                isSetFixer = true;
            }

            position -= mPositionFixer;

            if (position <= 1) {
                final float scaleFactor = Math.max(MIN_SCALE, 1 - Math.abs(position));
                final float vertMargin = pageHeight * (1 - scaleFactor) / 2;
                final float horzMargin = pageWidth * (1 - scaleFactor) / 2;

                if (position < 0) {
                    view.setTranslationX(horzMargin - vertMargin / 2);
                } else {
                    view.setTranslationX(-horzMargin + vertMargin / 2);
                }

                view.setScaleX(scaleFactor);
                view.setScaleY(scaleFactor);
            }
        }
    }
```

Although I cannot understand this bug in Support libraries rev. 23.2.0.