# Warning in ViewPager and TabLayout (not updated inline; expected state 3 found 2)

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, fragmentmanager

> compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0' using this version of support library.

*Gone through this link but could not found the exact solution*

> [Tab+ViewPager not updating instead shows weird warning expected state 3 found 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35810115/tabviewpager-not-updating-instead-shows-weird-warning-expected-state-3-found-2)
>
> [Android ViewPager Loading incorrect fragments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35783098/android-viewpager-loading-incorrect-fragments)

**W/FragmentManager: moveToState: Fragment state for A{7bb406c #3 id=0x7f0d0087} not updated inline; expected state 3 found 2**

> TabLayout and ViewPager in Activity.

```
if (tabLayout!=null) {
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("A"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("B"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("C"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("D"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("E"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("F"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("G"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("H"));
    }

    adapter=new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),tabLayout.getTabCount());
    mVPCompare.setAdapter(adapter);


    mVPCompare.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
    tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            mVPCompare.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition(),true);
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });
```

> Adapter Class.

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {


int pages;

public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm,int pages) {
    super(fm);
    this.pages=pages;
}
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {



    Fragment fragment;

    switch (position)
    {
        case 0:
            fragment=new A();
            return fragment;

        case 1:
            fragment=new B();
            return  fragment;

        case 2:
            fragment=new C();
            return fragment;

        case 3:
            fragment=new D();
            return fragment;

        case 4:
            fragment=new E();
            return fragment;

        case 5:
            fragment=new F();
            return fragment;

        case 6:
            fragment=new G();
            return fragment;

        case 7:
            fragment=new H();
            return fragment;

        default:
            return null;
    }

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return pages;
}
```

}